# Can not get GPS from my modem SIMCOM_SIM7600E-H

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, gps, mmcli

I have modem SIMCOM_SIM7600E-H and I can't get gps location

At first, I used this command `--location-enable-gps-raw`, and then this one `--location-get-gps-raw`

And I have `error: no actions specified`